# Pass in an instance variable to a static method -- and modifies another instance variance?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have a static method that takes in a `HashMap` and a few other parameters and modifies the `HashMap`:

`public static void foo(HashMap map, other parameters)`

Let's say I have a class called `Bar` that has two instance variable `HashMap`'s.

I pass one of these `HashMap`s into `foo`, intending it to be modified (and do not pass the other HashMap in). Am I correct in saying that it is *impossible* for the other `HashMap` to be modified by `foo` as a result of just this one method call?

I ask because this appears to be happening to me...

Comment: If both `Map`s share same mutable object references as key/values and they are modified by this `foo` method, then the changes will be reflected on both `Map`s.

Comment: this seems like a great learning experience for overriding methods (get and set) edit: Luiggi is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
Map<String,String> map1=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

and

```
Map<String,String> map2=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

If you pass map1 to a method, then any change to map1 will not be reflected in map2
because map1 and map2 are representing  two different object in the memory.
If you are assigning `map1=map2` then both maps are referencing the same object, so modifying one object will reflect in the other object reference. Java is passing object by reference (this is not 100% correct, value of the reference is passed).

For the same object reference stored in both maps you change the properties of the object on one map will reflect in object in the other object, because you are changing the behavior of the same object. It will reflect the changes where ever it is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in saying that it is impossible for the other HashMap to
>   be modified by foo as a result of just this one method call?

Answer is may be.

It is true that if you dont pass the reference of a object to method, you can not access it.

But Map stores key-value Object pair refernece, it does not store the Objects, if both map share Object as key or value, then it would effect.

Comment: Note that you can modify only the `Map` object reference passed, but looks like the problem OP's facing is about the object references stored in both `Map`s in form of key or value. If this is the real problem, then the changes made on one of the `Map`s will be reflected on the other `Map` as well.

Answer (score 0):

if its like

```
one = new HashMap();
two = one;
```

and you pass one to `public static void foo(HashMap map, other parameters)`
then changes done to one in method foo will effect two as well.

This happens because one and two both of them are pointing to same object.

Things will be different for

```
one = new HashMap();
two = new HashMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct in saying that it is impossible for the other `HashMap` to be modified by foo as a result of just this one method call?

If both `Map`s points to the same object reference, then changes made on one `Map` will affect the other map (as shown in Mangus' answer).

Assuming your `Map`s have different instances, then modifying one `Map` (i.e. putting or removing elements to/from the map) **will never** affect the other directly. **But** if the `Map`s share a common object reference in key or value and this object reference is modified in one of the `Map`s, then the object reference stored in the other `Map` will be modified as well. To show this in code:

```
class FooClass {
    private int fooInt;
    public FooClass(int fooInt) {
        this.fooInt = fooInt;
    }
    //getters and setters...
}
class MapHolder {
    private Map<String, FooClass> mapOne;
    private Map<String, FooClass> mapTwo;
    public MapHolder() {
        mapOne = new HashMap<>();
        mapTwo = new HashMap<>();
    }
    public void init() {
        FooClass foo = new FooClass(10);
        //note that we're putting the same FooClass object reference in both maps
        mapOne.put("foo", foo);
        mapTwo.put("bar", foo);
    }
    //getters and setters...
}
class TestMapModification {
    public static void foo(Map<String, FooClass> map, String key) {
        //for testing purposes, we will modify the value of the passed key
        FooClass foo = map.get(key);
        if (foo != null) {
            foo.setFooInt(foo.getFooInt() * 2);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapHolder mapHolder = new MapHolder();
        mapHolder.init();
        System.out.println(mapHolder.getMapOne().get("foo").getFooInt());
        System.out.println(mapHolder.getMapTwo().get("bar").getFooInt());
        foo(mapHolder.getMapOne(), "foo");
        System.out.println("But I just modified mapOne!");
        System.out.println(mapHolder.getMapOne().get("foo").getFooInt());
        System.out.println(mapHolder.getMapTwo().get("bar").getFooInt());
    }
}
```

Results of executing the code

```
10
10
But I just modified mapOne!
20
20
```